# lossless conversion of wmv to mp4 video in Ubuntu command line

Tags: command-line, video, convert, video-conversion

How can I losslessly convert a wmv video to mp4 using Ubuntu (20.04) command line?

Comment: It would be helpful to show what codecs are in your wmv video. If both are compatible with an mp4 container you could run: `ffmpeg -i input.wmv -codec copy output mp4` and this would simply copy all streams over to a new container without potentially lossy re-encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains input.wmv and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i input.wmv output.mp4
```

The input and output videos were the same dimensions and approximately the same size when I tested the command.

Comment: The OP requested for a `lossless` conversion.